# Jackson Yaml Type Info is wrong on serialization

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am getting the following output when serializing an object to yml via Jackson:

```
---
commands:
  dev: !<foo.bar.baz.DevCommand>
```

However, what I want is:

```
---
commands:
  dev: 
    type: foo.bar.baz.DevCommand
```

I am able to deserialize that fine.  That is to say, the deserialization part works as intended.  I have put the following annotation everywhere I can think of:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
```

Including on the DevCommand interface, on DevCommand the concrete class, on the type which has the `commands` map (both the field and the getters/setters).

What do I need to do to force Jackson to use the type format I want?

Comment: From doc of JsonTypeInfo: *Annotation used for configuring details of if and how type information is used with **JSON** serialization and deserialization* – since you serialize to YAML, it is simply not applicable and Jackson uses YAML's tag system instead.

Comment: @flyx But it uses the JsonTypeInfo annotation to configure the deserialization of the yaml....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yaml has type information built in already, so Jackson uses that by default. From [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues/79), the fix is to disable using the native type id.

> YAML has native Type Ids and Object Ids, so by default those are used
>   (assuming this is what users prefer). But you can disable this with:
>
> ```
> YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID
> ```
>
> and specifically disabling that; something like:
>
> ```
> YAMLFactory f = new YAMLFactory();
> f.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID);
> ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper(f);
> ```
>
> or, for convenience
>
> ```
> YAMLMapper m = new YAMLMapper()
>  disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID);
> ```

Comment: You're awesome dude! Thanks!