# How to de/serialize an instance with dynamically typed attribute

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

What would be the best way to serialize/deserialize instances of MyClass using Jackson?

```
class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private MyInterface classInstance;

    // standard getters setters
}
```

Attribute classInstance can be of an arbitrary type which implements  interface MyInterface

Ideally I'd like the yaml structure to look like this

```
name: com.example.ClassE
classInstance: 
  value: 42
  category: "fancy"
```

Notice that the "name" attribute actually contains a fully qualified type of the object inside "classInstance" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `JsonTypeInfo` annotation. It can generate `class` property for you and deserialise `YAML` payload using this property. Check below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        YAMLFactory yamlFactory = new YAMLFactory();
        yamlFactory.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yamlFactory);

        serialiseAndDeserialise(mapper, new MyValue());
        serialiseAndDeserialise(mapper, new MyBigDecimal());
    }

    private static void serialiseAndDeserialise(ObjectMapper mapper, MyInterface myInterface) throws java.io.IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setInstance(myInterface);

        String yaml = mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);
        System.out.println(yaml);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(yaml, MyClass.class));
    }
}

class MyClass {

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "name")
    private MyInterface instance;

    public MyInterface getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setInstance(MyInterface instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass{" +
                "instance=" + instance +
                '}';
    }
}

interface MyInterface {
}

class MyValue implements MyInterface {
    private int value = 42;
    private String category = "fancy";

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyValue{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class MyBigDecimal implements MyInterface {
    private BigDecimal pi = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI);

    public BigDecimal getPi() {
        return pi;
    }

    public void setPi(BigDecimal pi) {
        this.pi = pi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBigDecimal{" +
                "pi=" + pi +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
---
instance:
  name: "com.celoxity.MyValue"
  value: 42
  category: "fancy"

MyClass{instance=MyValue{value=42, category='fancy'}}
---
instance:
  name: "com.celoxity.MyBigDecimal"
  pi: 3.141592653589793

MyClass{instance=MyBigDecimal{pi=3.141592653589793}}
```

If you want to move `name` on the same level as `instance` change only annotation to:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "name")
```

And output will change to:

```
---
instance:
  value: 42
  category: "fancy"
name: "com.celoxity.MyValue"

MyClass{instance=MyValue{value=42, category='fancy'}}
---
instance:
  pi: 3.141592653589793
name: "com.celoxity.MyBigDecimal"

MyClass{instance=MyBigDecimal{pi=3.141592653589793}}
```

I prefer first one, because it informs that `name` property belongs to `instance`. If you remove `name` property from annotation `Jackson` will use default name for this kind of `use` - `'@class'`.

See also:

- [Jackson Yaml Type Info is wrong on serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272165/jackson-yaml-type-info-is-wrong-on-serialization)
- [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)
- [More Jackson Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)